# How to use Regasm.exe to Completely Unregister a AssemblyFile

Tags: .net, dll, frameworks, .net-assembly, regasm

I tried the following command to unregisters AssemblyFile:

```
regasm "AssemblyFilePath" /unregister /silent
```

However, it still leaves the such registry entries:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0039733E-1312-4535-B292-68A5137FE367}\InprocServer32]
" "="Mindjet.MindManager.Interop, Version=10.0.445.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19247b5ea06b230f"
"Class"="Mindjet.MindManager.Interop.AttachmentClass"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0039733E-1312-4535-B292-68A5137FE367}\InprocServer32\10.0.445.0]
"Assembly"="Mindjet.MindManager.Interop, Version=10.0.445.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19247b5ea06b230f"
"Class"="Mindjet.MindManager.Interop.AttachmentClass"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
```

So, is there a way to remove the left entries automatically? thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assembly itself is actually responsible for the registration and unregistration, so it's possible there's an issue in the actual assembly that's not removing those entries.

The answer to your question completely depends on the context. In the case of an uninstaller, I would suggest just using code to manually remove those entries since you know they are going to be there.

I have an installer where I used to call RegAsm to register/unregister but I decided it was much easier to just include the code in the installer to add/remove the registry entries instead of using RegAsm which is effectively the same thing.

Comment: Chris (or anyone else in the know on this) could you elaborate on what issues might cause the assembly to fail to remove the CLSID entries?  We're encountering this situation now and I'm having trouble finding any information on how to properly build an assembly so that it can remove its CLSID entries on unregistration.